# What are prototypes in programming?

Tags: language-agnostic, function-prototypes

This isn't a specific question about a language, but more about programming in general. The question came after I started an argument with a friend about "Function prototypes" which I learnt about recently from my C++ course. I mentioned to him that prototypes are function headers that you have to create at the beginning of your code so the compiler allocates some space at runtime before getting to the actual function. We then started rambling about whether other programming languages (Like java or python) which do not utilize function prototypes -- so far as we're concerned -- actually had a system similar to that of C++, just that they handled it themselves rather than having the user create them.

So we're curious to know, what are function prototypes after all? Are they only accountable on C/C++, or do other programming languages make use of them? And is it something I'd need to develop more on as a future programmer? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to C and C++, the word "prototype" refers to a specific declaration syntax.

In the earliest versions of C, function definitions were written as

```
int func( arg1, arg2, arg3 ) // no types in argument list, just identifiers
  int arg1;
  double arg2;
  char *arg3;
{
  // function body
}
```

and declarations were written as

```
int func( ); // no argument list
```

The function argument list only contained identifiers and no type information - that was supplied separately.  Function declarations didn't include arguments, just the return type.

C++ introduced and C later adopted the concept of *prototype syntax*, where the type information is included in the parameter list in both the definition:

```
int func( int arg1, double arg2, char *arg3 )
{
  // function body
}
```

and the declaration

```
int func( int, double, char * );
```

This allowed compilers to check the number *and types* of arguments in a function call and issue diagnostics if they didn't match, rather than waiting until runtime to find out if there's a problem.

While the old-style function declaration and definition syntax is still supported, it should not be used for new code development - we're almost to the point where the word "prototype" is kind of redundant, since prototype syntax is the norm rather than the exception.

Statically-typed languages like Fortran and Pascal and Ada all have separate function *declarations*, but they don't refer to those declarations as prototypes.  And again with C, "prototype" refers to a specific *style* of function declaration and definition, not just a declaration in and of itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is greatly oversimplified, but the reason for function prototypes is "one-pass compilers."

If your compiler only makes one pass through the code, it needs to know what functions are available to it, before the function implementation is called.  This is where prototypes come in.

Compilers that make multiple passes through the code build jump tables that tell it where all the functions are, so there's no need for function prototypes.

---

In C compilers, prototypes are used to check the type and number of function parameters (i.e. the function signature).  This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",add(3));
}

int add(int i, int j)
{
    return i+j;
}
```

[compiles and executes in Clang 7 with a warning](https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/LikableProudDevelopments#main.c), even though the result is meaningless (i.e. undefined behavior).

Whereas this program, incorporating a function prototype:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add (int, int); /* function prototype for add */

void main()
{
    printf("%d\n",add(3));
}

int add(int i, int j)
{
    return i+j;
}
```

[fails to compile](https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/HeavenlyOldfashionedInterfaces#main.c).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but what you're describing is more a characteristic of a function _declaration_ than a prototype. At least in C, what is called a "prototype" is just a function name/return without the signature known (`void foo()` is a prototype, but `void foo(void)` is a declaration). Languages like C++ don't even have prototypes (at least, not in the C definition); it only has declarations.

Comment: @Human-Compiler I think this term might be used differently in different environments. Wikipedia for example disagrees with you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype

Comment: After double-checking the C standard, it appears I was wrong in my statement above (I had the concept inverted). C refers to prototypes to mean the function declaration _with the parameter list_, whereas a function declarator contains an empty list (though this is a legacy/obsolescent feature). My apologies!

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ are compiled to native code and support calling between compilation units (files). To call a function XYZ from a neighboring compilation unit the compiler inserts a reference "calling XYZ" which is later resolved by the linker. But you need to know what to prepare on the stack for the function. The prototype supplies that information without having to compile the whole function.

Early C treated everything as int and as the C calling convention is caller-cleans-up, you as the caller know how many ints to remove from the stack after a function returns. If you call `printf` with three arguments without explaining what it is, the C compiler can still figure out what code to generate. If you misspelled it to `vrintf` it will compile but fail to link. So plain C worked (still works?) to some extent without prototypes (or treats missing prototypes as just a warning).

As C++ can pass all kinds of crazy stuff as function arguments, if you try to call something without explaining its argument types first, the compiler does not know what code to generate and you get an error.

This outside article is reasonably nice: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/yAqpX9L8/

Comment: That article was really helpful! Thanks a lot!